# Declare global var from Template File and use it in Functions.php

Tags: author, globals, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I am using the wpseo_title filter to rewrite the authors page titles from my site.

I have the following code in author.php template:

```
<?php 
   global $author_page_titles;
   $author_page_titles = $curauth->nickname .', Preparador de Oposiciones a '. $term_especialidad->name .' en '. $term_region->name;
?>
```

Which outputs ***Kevin, Preparador de Oposiciones a Forestales en Madrid*** in my author page (in other pages is the given author nickname and his/her selected terms).

In my functions.php I have the following function:

```
function my_custom_authorpage_title($author_page_titles) {
  if (is_author()) {
    global $author_page_titles;
    return $author_page_titles;
  }
}
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'my_custom_authorpage_title', 100);
```

I'm pretty sure that the mistake must be in how and where I declare the var, but can't find the solution.

Comment: in general if your solution includes creating a global then your solution is wrong. You should ask yourself if you need the global in the first place.

Comment: Could you explain me why? I have read that is ok, that WordPress use globals all the time, and also that is not a good practice.

Comment: Globals prevent true modulation of code, like in this question you can never know if they are initialized or not. Wordpress uses many globals and that is very confusing and many times newbies will use them wrong. Globals are like goto, they typically should not be used except for some very rare situations in which that is the best option. And don't get more software development advice from that friend :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the exact same filter in your template files. If you do need it in functions.php for any reason (maybe you have some additional processing) then you can use your own custom filter.

functions.php:

```
function my_custom_authorpage_title( $title ) {
    // process ...
    return apply_filters( 'my_title', $title );
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_title', 'my_custom_authorpage_title' );
```

author.php (before `get_header()`):

```
add_filter( 'my_title', function( $title ) use ( $curauth, $term_especialidad, $term_region ) {
    return $curauth->nickname . '...';
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello @kovshenin, using the filter code directly into the author.php template file doesn't work, and using it with a custom filter as you indicated ignores the $curauth->nickname and $term_region/$term_especialidad.

Comment: Kevin, could you show the full code for both files that you have tried?

Comment: Hello @kovshenin I included the vars before the add_filter, on top of the author.php template and it solved the problem. Thank you.